# Generate full XML configuration from Spring 3 annotations

Tags: spring, frameworks, annotations, spring-3

Is there is a way to generate full XML configuration file based on Spring 3 annotations scattered all over the classes?

Ideally, I'm looking for a tool that can "parse" a Spring 3 project and output XML configuration, something [like xdoclet was doing](http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/tags/spring-tags.html#@spring_bean__0__1_) (but off course from Spring annotations)

Is there a tool like this, or a way I could write my own if none exists?

Answer (score 2):

You can always write your own.  I'm not aware of one.

Funny, because annotations were added because some people complained about heavy XML configuration.  You're swimming against the tide here.

Just curious - why do you want the XML now?  Why aren't the annotations sufficient?

Comment: I just want the full picture :D. XML config, ugly or not, provided the full picture. I'm currently migrating from Spring 2.5.x and exclusively used XML up'till now. I'm looking to tie new concepts to old ones that I was familiar with and a side by side comparison of annotation vs XML I think will help me go faster.

Comment: @ElenaT I would also like this, but for a different reason - using google app engine with spring scanning can cause slow startup of new instances.  To increase performance I've seen using xml suggested instead, but I'd like to generate that from the config as part of the build so the scanning doesn't have to be done when every instance starts up

Comment: You only start up once.   If the cost is amortized over a long period of steady runtime, what's the difference?

Comment: As @ElenaT mentioned, Google highly recommends to use XML-based configuration instead of annotation-based. In my opinion annotations are way readable and easier to debug. It would be great if someone have found solution to convert annotations to XML automatically.